# Collaborative space for uploading and annotating pdfs

Tags: pdf

In Edge, I can easily annotate and add comments to pdfs.

What's an online tool that lets me upload pdfs (or websites) into a collaborative space where I can perform annotations and have it stored in the cloud to be shared with others?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick research, I've found that it is possible to upload files and therefore also PDF files to a Miro board. After uploading you can collectively annotate and comment the content of the PDF files.

Check out the guide from the [official Miro help pages](https://help.miro.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017731013-Uploading-files-to-boards).